# Sending Email - Error

Tags: c#

I am trying to send email using the following piece of code in Winforms app.
Username and Password are correct and real- but have masked in the code.

I don't know wheather my local machine has the capacity to send emails or not?

But please advise me , What do I need to look at my machine Configuration(in IIS)?

ERROR: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 209.85.143.109:587"

```
//All Variable Declarations
String senderAddress = string.Empty;
String receiveraddress = string.Empty;
String emailSubject = string.Empty;
String emailMessageText = string.Empty;
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);


private void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      try
      {
            //Get the Values of Controls

            senderAddress = txtSenderEmail.Text;
            receiveraddress = txtReceiverEmail.Text;
            emailSubject = txtSubject.Text;
            emailMessageText = txtMessageBody.Text;

            //Pass the Values
            mail.From = new MailAddress(senderAddress, "xxxxxxxxxx", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            mail.To.Add(receiveraddress);
            mail.Subject = emailSubject;
            mail.Body = emailMessageText;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxx");
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(mail);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Email Sent Successfully");



      }
      catch (Exception mailException)
      {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Message Not Sent ,Error:   " + mailException.Message);
            throw;
      }
      finally
      {

      }



}
```

I have done a telnet for both the ports and the error comes is : Could not open connection to the host.

Please look at the following pic, it should give you more clarity,

[image]

Comment: Minor side note: Storing `mail` as a member `mail.To.Add(receiveraddress);` will cause the "to" field to be expanded with each mail sent unless I missed something about the class or missing code.

Comment: Works for me ;) - it seems you have some networking problem to connect to 209.85.143.109 using port 465, therefore you should contact your ISP or check from some other computer in your network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GMail requires you to use SSL](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287). The port you need to use for TLS/STARTTLS is 587. For SSL it is 465. Below is code you can use to send email via the command-line. [CommandLine.Utility](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/command_line.aspx) can be downloaded at CodeProject.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.ComponentModel;
using CommandLine.Utility;

namespace SmtpClientProgram
{
    class Program
    {        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Arguments cmdLine = new Arguments(args);        

            SmtpClient mailer = new SmtpClient();

            // --ssl means we are using SSL/TLS

            mailer.EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(cmdLine["ssl"]);

            // -host=smtp.gmail.com

            if (cmdLine["host"] != null)
                mailer.Host = cmdLine["host"];
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hostname must be specified");
                return;
            }

            // -port=25

            if (cmdLine["port"] != null)
                try
                {
                    mailer.Port = Convert.ToInt32(cmdLine["port"]);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Port must be a number between 1 and 65535");
                }
            else
                mailer.Port = 25;

            // -user= -password=
            if (cmdLine["user"] != null && cmdLine["password"] != null)
            {                
                mailer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(cmdLine["user"], cmdLine["password"]);
            }

            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

                mail.From = new MailAddress(cmdLine["from"], cmdLine["name"]);

                if (cmdLine["to1"] != null)
                    mail.To.Add(cmdLine["to1"]);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Must specify first TO address");

                if (cmdLine["to2"] != null)
                    mail.To.Add(cmdLine["to2"]);

                if (cmdLine["to3"] != null)
                    mail.To.Add(cmdLine["to3"]);

                if (cmdLine["subject"] != null)
                    mail.Subject = cmdLine["subject"];

                if (cmdLine["body"] != null)
                    mail.Body = cmdLine["body"];

                mailer.Send(mail);

                //mailer.Send(cmdLine["from"], cmdLine["to"], cmdLine["subject"], cmdLine["body"]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Success");            
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: If you cannot connect to port 587 (service may be down), then try 465 with SSL or 25 with SSL. See [here for Gmail help on sending email](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78775).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that problem is not with your code, but with SMTP server you want to use. Check if port 587 on machine 209.85.143.109 is open and accepting SMTP commands.

Comment: I can ping 209.85.143.109 though the command prompt when I try to ping 209.85.143.109:587, No Reply comes back.

Comment: @Hari: You have to use telnet. ICMP (Ping) does not use a port. I can't telnet into 587 either. Try 465 instead.

Comment: But telneting port 465 will afaik connect with SMTP over SSL, so you won't be able to easily check if there is smtp there.

Comment: If you can telnet to smtp.gmail.com on port 465 and do not get connection refused, you can reasonably assume that smtp service is running on that port. All Hari has to do is change his port and try it.

Comment: 20A0D - yeah, you are right. So, Hari: SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",465); is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This generally means that either there is no mail server running at the location specified or you need to configure your firewalls to let the connection through and setup your router to forward the connections for 587 to the right server IP on your network.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like it's going to some SMTP server, which either your IIS is forwarding to or your organizations SMTP server.

If it's just for development, you can use the PickUP directory feature which would let you test withtout having any SMTP setup. Good amount of information exists on google

EDIT

Removed google link. Some people did not like it. Though I did not mean to offend anyone, I still removed, but my intention remains to help

Comment: Hello Mr Dike, you are smart guy, But your smartness is not helpful in this case as you literally pointing me to do a google click. So for that I am marking you down

Comment: @Hari & someone else, thanks for Criticism . I welcome if thats constructive. Reason I merely pointed to google just because Pickup directory usage has so many samples out there and you can have choices of any code you might like. It's fairly fine to put a simple code here itself but why duplicate if large amount of information exists.

Comment: its not duplicate code, If anybody wants to help me, they should see my code,  they should know, What caused the error, For that reason I have posted my code, without posting mycode, People willing to answer my question will find problematic. So I am not duplicating anything. So kindly don't point to this kind of answers. Thanks for your time again.

Comment: @Hari: I think you are misunderstanding how PING and TELNET and network connections work in general. See my comments and answers.

Comment: Could any body try to help me please, when I telnet to both ports, it comes up with message could not open connection to host, What do I need to look at now? Thank you

Comment: @Hari: You have a computer/network problem then. I can connect to it from the US with no problems. Recommend you move this question to superuser.com or serverfault.com.