# Sending Email-SMTP Problem-C#.NET

Tags: c#, smtp

I am struggling with this problem from yesterday.

**What I have done so far?**

I have used the code to send an email using local smtp server. Code is(C#.Net) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730867/sending-email-error).

I can telnet the localhost on port 25.

When I telnet: "220 DomainName Microsoft6 ESMTP Mail Service, Version 6.0.3790.3959 Ready at Date Time "

When I try to send the email, there are no errors in the code and code gets executed successfully without any error.

Errors:

**When I check in the eventviewer, the error is : Message Delivery to Host 74.125.159.27 failed while delivering to the remote domain gmail.com for the following reason. The remote server did not respond to a connection attempt.**

I know there is error in my SMTP Server Setup, I have not set it up properly. How do I Trouble shoot it.

I have downloaded a smtpdiag.exe from microsoft but, It doesn't do anything when clicking on .exe file loads up and disappears.

**Resolutions Please?**

Please help me how do I troubleshoot it. If you need more information please ask me, I will provide but try to help me

Thank you.

Comment: Server configuration questions are better suited to http://serverfault.com

Comment: This belongs on serverfault - it's a server setup question.

Comment: gmail blocks IPs from some ISPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending emails through IIS SMTP Server right?

And you are sending to your gmail address?

How OFTEN do you send them? Google as a kind of spam protection that fakes that the servers is not responding if an IP address tries to send too many emails at once.

There is a thread here at SO about it. But I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Thanks jgauffin. I have tried to send to yahoo, my organisation emails as well. nothing gets sent

Comment: Ahh. Are you sure that your Internet Service Prvoider allows you to send emails through any SMTP server? Many of them blocks port 25. Try to telnet to smtp.gmail.com on port 25

Comment: I have changed to local host and port 25 , but its still same problem

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. A local SMTP server have the same problem if your ISP blocks port 25. Try using your ISPs SMTP Server instead.